# Why does my slider go blank after reaching the end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a two issues/problems with the following slide. 
It is a "double slider", so, two simultaneous slider in body section.

First is that when i reach the last image (9-nth, cos that much both sliders contain), the second slider continues to work properly (sliding images infinitely) but the first one just get blank. 
Or if i click on previous button on begining then second doesn't work and images disapear, while the first one work nicely. Can't figure it out why. I've tried changing the "id" in the HTML and styling it but nothing change.

---

Second is, that i finally need to make it more dynamic, so, to avoid hardcoding images in the HTML and to putt them in JS and somehow append them in the DOM, but don't know what exactlly to do; creating an array, or using the "createElement"?

And which logic could be usable to actually include them in the DOM and have the following slider(s), considering the provided code? 
Since it's my just second slider which i'm making, i found it pretty much hard, so any help/hint/advice is welcomed.

P.S Must be in jQuery and plugins excluded, so please don't provide any plugins links.

Thank you in advance.

```js
var slides = $('.slide');

slides.first().before(slides.last());

$('button').on('click', function() {
  // Selecting the slides
  slides = $('.slide');
  // Selecting button
  var button = $(this);
  // Register active slide
  var activeSlide = $('.active');

  // Next function
  if (button.attr('id') == 'next') {

    slides.last().after(slides.first());

    activeSlide.removeClass('active').next('.slide').addClass('active');
  }

  // Previous function
  if (button.attr('id') == 'previous') {

    slides.first().before(slides.last());

    activeSlide.removeClass('active').prev('.slide').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.slide.active {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.slide.active~.slide {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: aqua;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide active">
    <img src="Assets/slider-image-1.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="Assets/slider-image-2.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="Assets/slider-image-3.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="Assets/slider-image-4.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="Assets/slider-image-5.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="Assets/slider-image-6.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="Assets/slider-image-7.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="Assets/slider-image-8.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="Assets/slider-image-9.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide active">
    <img src="Assets/slider-image-1.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="Assets/slider-image-2.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="Assets/slider-image-3.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="Assets/slider-image-4.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="Assets/slider-image-5.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="Assets/slider-image-6.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="Assets/slider-image-7.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="Assets/slider-image-8.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="Assets/slider-image-9.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<button id="previous"><img src="Assets/arrow-blue-left.png" alt=""></button>
<button id="next"><img src="Assets/arrow-blue-right.png" alt=""></button>
```

Comment: Please don't ask two questions at a time. If possible, reduce to one and post a second question.

Comment: I apologise if that is against the rules. I am new to stackowerflow community and it's just my second post. 
I didn't wanted to get annoying with slider thing and questions over and over so i tought that will be better to combine it into one post.
And yeah, thanks for letting me know that to.

Comment: No problem. It's sometimes difficult to accept a suitable answer if you have two distinct questions with different acceptance requirements. Better to keep them separate and clear.

Comment: I understand. 
Just curious since i'm not yet  in the flow, is it allowed to post code of some small finished project?

Comment: It's not normally done, but you could add it to the bottom of your question.

Comment: Alright, got.it.
Idea is that someone who struggles with same issues on beginning of developer path, can search something similar and maybe find it useful in some aspects of work/project.
And yeah, thanks again for infos, to know for future. :)

Comment: Sure. In most cases, what's provided in the answer(s) accomplishes that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2. Loading images dinamically: You can do that by defining an array which contains the images and you can append the images into the slider using the jQuery 'append' method. Working example on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tnpv3b4j/2/).

   ```
   function fillSliders(slider, images) {
       $(slider).empty();
       for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
           if(typeof images[i] == "string" && images[i] !== "") {
               var active = (i == 1) ? " active" : "";
               $(slider).append('<div class="slide'+active+'"><img src="'+images[i]+'" 
                                 alt="image-'+i+'" /></div>');
           }
       }
   }
   var images = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg","image3.jpg","image4.jpg"];
   fillSliders($("#slider"), images);
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was of great help.

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work properly because the `slides = $('.slide')` variable contains all slides from both sliders. You have to manipulate the slides in the to sliders independently. The second failure is that in your example the first slide is the initial active slide. Only slides in range second -> penultimate are allowed. Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/batcm29o/3/)

```
function handleSlide(slider, direction) {
  var slides = $(slider).find('.slide');
  if(slides.length < 1) return;

  // Register active slide
  var activeSlide = $(slider).find('.active');

  // Next function
  if (direction == 'next') {
    slides.last().after(slides.first());
    activeSlide.removeClass('active').next('.slide').addClass('active');
  }

  // Previous function
  if (direction == 'previous') {
    slides.first().before(slides.last());
    activeSlide.removeClass('active').prev('.slide').addClass('active');
  }
}

$('button').on('click', function() {
    var button = $(this);
    handleSlide($("#slider1"), $(button).attr('id'));
  handleSlide($("#slider2"), $(button).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Gosh, thanks a lot!
I will look over it more closely.
Could you advice me for the second part of the problem, which way would be better (and easier, considering i'm still a beginner); 
making the array with images, or going with "createElement", or maybe something else?

Comment: 'createElement' is a plain javascript function. I think is easier to make an array and use the '$(slider).append(...)' jQuery method instead.